# How to show a local img already saved

Tags: javascript, html, forms, image, local-storage

I am a very jr and i am working on a e-commerce project and i want to show a local img that was saved previously in a form with localstorage(i think thats the part that dont work)(its my first question so i dont know how to show mi code properly)
How i said i am a little jr so i dont need efficiently code, i need a code that i can understand
Thanks :D

I have

```
<div id="headerInline">
        <h2>Perfil</h2><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34AD2.jpg" id="profilePictureView" width="100" height="100">
</div>


            <label for="profilePicture" class="form-label">Imagen de perfil</label>
            <input type="file" id="profilePicture" class="form-control" onchange="previewFile()">
            <br>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Guardar cambios</button>
            </div>
```

```
function previewFile() {
    const preview = document.querySelector('img');
    const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
  
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      preview.src = reader.result;
    }, false);
  
    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

let fields = document.querySelectorAll('input')
function saveData() {
  localStorage.setItem("profileName", fields[0].value)
  localStorage.setItem("profileSecondName", fields[1].value)
  localStorage.setItem("profileLastname", fields[2].value)
  localStorage.setItem("profileSecondLastname", fields[3].value)
  localStorage.setItem("profileTelephone", fields[5].value)
  localStorage.setItem("profilePic", fields[6].value)
}
function dataSaved() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("userEmail") !== null) {
    fields[0].value = localStorage.getItem("profileName")
    fields[1].value = localStorage.getItem("profileSecondName")
    fields[2].value = localStorage.getItem("profileLastname")
    fields[3].value = localStorage.getItem("profileSecondLastname")
    fields[5].value = localStorage.getItem("profileTelephone")
    // fields[6].value = previewFile()
    // document.getElementById("profilePictureView").src = previewFile().result
    // console.log(fields[6])
  } else {
  }
}
dataSaved();
```

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0xhe1vy/1/) of your code that saves the profile image to localStorage.  Note that localStorage has a 4mb limit and so you will want to reject huge images or else resize them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.